# WEKA RandomForest model loading. Weka exception: No training file and no object input file given

Tags: shell, weka

I am currently using two shell scripts to train/test Random Forest model.
When I train the model I have no problems at all. However, when calling the test.sh which tries to load the model, generates the following error:

```
Weka exception: No training file and no object input file given.

General options:

-h or -help
    Output help information.
-synopsis or -info
    Output synopsis for classifier (use in conjunction  with -h)
-t <name of training file>
    Sets training file.
...
```

In train.sh I have:

```
 java -Xmx1g -classpath $CLASSPATH:weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest \
    -t "$FileNameFeaturesTrain_weka" \
    -no-cv \
    -I $numTrees -K $numFeat -S 0 \
    -p 0 -distribution -d "$fileNameModel" > "$fname_output_pred"
```

In test.sh I have:

```
java -Xmx1g -classpath $CLASSPATH:weka.jar weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest \
    -l "$FileNameModel" \
    -T "$FileNameFeaturesTest_weka" \
    -no-cv \
    -p 0 -distribution > "$fname_output_pred"
```

I don't understand why is the model not loading in my test.sh script. However the same logic and flags work well with weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic, weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron, etc. This error is only happening with RandomForest. I am using WEKA 3.6.12. 
I would appreciate any tips or comments.
Thank you,

Comment: I have found an alternative to fix this problem. Just for those who may happen to face similar things, you can use WEKA filters and the flag -serialize. The code is as follows:
`java 
 weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AddClassification
 -serialized "$fileNameModel"
 -classification
 -distribution
 -i "$FileNameFeaturesTest_weka"
 -c last > "$fname_output_pred_test"`